# Vaadin23 refresh/re-render Grid column row on demand

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I use Grid component with 1 column and have a lot of information in such column in each row. Also, I use Grid Details and show specific form there. After the user action in the form, I need to refresh/re-render the Grid row in order to reflect the most recent changes. Please advise how to let the Grid know in order to refresh/re-render the specific row.

Comment: Have you tried `getDataProvider().refreshItem(item)` ?

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried. The problem with this method is that the details windows also close.

Comment: You can programmatically open the details row with `grid.setDetailsVisible(item ,true);`